# Отделить день недели от времени в строке формата "дд:чч:мм:сс"? c#

Tags: c#

Вот такая таблица есть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В столбце dt_send_daytime указано время в формате дд:чч:мм:сс. Где *дд* - номер дня недели. Если в name_ru = час, то нужно взять только время в формате *мм:сс*. А если name_ru = Неделя, то только день недели.

Как отделить день недели от времени?

Comment: дд - это день недели?

Comment: А не проще хранить день недели отдельно от времени?

Comment: да это день недели

Comment: просто на базе данных так написано,мне надо это решать(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка такого вида как у вас записана в базе, не распознается как ДатаВремя. Необходимо ее разобрать на части. Для этого существует метод [string.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a(v=vs.100).aspx). Получим массив. Нулевой элемент будет день недели.

```
string dt_str = row["dt_send_datetime"];
string[] dt_str_tmp = st_str.Split(':');

switch (row["name_ru"])
{
  case "Час":
       // Можно сразу так. В итоге получим к примеру 4:0
       Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[2]+":"+dt_str_tmp[3]);

       // Можно конвертировать во время 
       // DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", dt_str_tmp[1], dt_str_tmp[2], dt_str_tmp[3]));
       // и потом вывести
       // Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("mm:ss"); 
       // В итоге получим 04:00

       break;
  case "Неделя":
       Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[0]);
       break;
}
```

Можно заменить весь `switch`, при условии что выбор только из двух значений - "час" или "неделя", на:

`Console.WriteLine((name_ru == "Час")?dt_str_tmp[2]+":"+dt_str_tmp[3]:dt_str_tmp[0]);`

Comment: вместо ("mm:ss") можно  писать (tmp[1]:tmp[2]) ???

Comment: не совсем. подправил ответ

Comment: Ошибка 'row["dt_send_datetime"]' , это у меня объект а не стринг

Comment: А просто `row["dt_send_datetime"].ToString()` не катит?

Comment: а теперь на (row["name_ru"])

Comment: да тоже самое. `row["name"].ToString()`

Comment: теперь на всех tmp[] ошибка что не так???

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39848/discussion-between-maximk-and-propro17).

Comment: а если в таблице будет строка и `час`  и  `Час`???

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.toupper(v=vs.110).aspx переводи строку в верхний регистр

Comment: Прочитал, не понял как переводить(

Comment: `switch (string.ToUpper(row["time_name_ru"]))`  не удается преобразовать из объекта в  `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`

Comment: если в колонке будет `часы` то этот код не работает да получается

Comment: Ответил тебе в соседнем вопросе

Comment: поможете таймером

Answer (score 0):

Из БД получайте полную дату, приводите к типу DateTime и используйте метод ToString(). 
Например `string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") // выведет текущую дату в формате ЧЧ:ММ`

Конкретно в вашем случае

```
string dt;
if (row["name_ru"] == "Час")
{
    dt = row["dt_send_daytime"].ToString("mm:ss");
}
else if (row["name_ru"] == "Неделя")
{
    dt = row["dt_send_daytime"].ToString("dd");
}
```

Comment: Строка такого формата как у автора, не будет распознана как ДатаВремя

Comment: такое решение не подойдёт да получается???

Comment: Попробуй. Вылезет ошибка.